# ¿Como comparar 2 fechas con formato 20-02-2022? en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una duda sobre el comprar 2 fechas y ejecutar una tarea en caso de que sean diferentes, pero el resultado obtenido es que realiza la validación y manda el mensaje aunque no se cumpla la regla, estas fechas vienen de un elemento input de html con el formato 20-02-2022, no se si estoy omitiendo algo me podrían ayudar a saber si se me esta pasando algo.

```js
var fecha1 = $(#fecha_1).val(); 
var fecha2 = $(#fecha_2).val(); 

if (new Date(fecha1).getTime() != new Date(fecha2).getTime()){
       mensajesdeerror.push("las fechas no coinciden, cambialas");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Javascript el constructor de `Date` sólo acepta formatos válidos para [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), y entre esos formatos no se encuentra el formato actual de tu fecha: día-mes-año.

Para construir tu fecha, puedes dividirla en partes, usando `split()` y luego pasar las partes al constructor de una forma que este las acepte: `año, mes, dia`, [según la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Haremos todo eso desde una función `createDate`, que nos ayudará a simplificar el código.

```js
var fecha1 = $('#fecha_1').val();
var fecha2 = $('#fecha_2').val();


if (createDate(fecha1).getTime() != createDate(fecha2).getTime()) {
  console.log('No son iguales');
} else {
  console.log('Son iguales');

}

function createDate(dateString) {
  /*
    Dividimos la cadena por el separador
    */
  var dateParts = dateString.split("-");
  /* 
    En Javascript el mes es 0-based, 
    por eso restamos 1 a la parte del mes
    mediante dataParts[1] - 1
    Y usamos Date.UTC para que ignore la zona horaria
    esto puedes quitarlo si no interesa
    */
  return new Date(Date.UTC(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fecha_1" value="20-02-2022" />
<input id="fecha_2" value="20-02-2022" />
```

---

Otra posibilidad interesante te la ofrece [la librería moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), a partir de la cual puedes crear fechas desde formatos no estándar, comparar, etc.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var fecha1 = $('#fecha_1').val();
var fecha2 = $('#fecha_2').val();

if (!moment(fecha1, "DD-MM-YYYY").isSame(moment(fecha2, "DD-MM-YYYY"))) {
  console.log('No son iguales');
} else {
  console.log('Son iguales');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fecha_1" value="20-02-2022" />
<input id="fecha_2" value="20-02-2022" />
```

Comment: Hola gracias por esos datos estimado no había tomado en cuenta el formato de fecha que es valido apara el método getTime(), tendré mas cuidado en revisar la documentación de los métodos, realice estos cambios en mi código y efectivamente funciono con el resultado esperado, mil gracias estimado.

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que tus fechas tengan el formato '20-02-2022', puedes hacer uso del método Date.parse(fecha), el cuál dada una fecha te devuelve la fecha en milisegundos. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var fecha1 = $(#fecha_1).val(); 
var fecha2 = $(#fecha_2).val(); 
if (Date.parse(fecha1) != Date.parse(fecha2)){
   mensajesdeerror.push("las fechas no coinciden, cambialas");
}
```

Comment: Hola estimando antes de usar el metodo getTime, ya habia intentado parsearla obteniendo el mismo resultado, pero aun asi gracias por tu ayuda estimado.